# I cant spot my basic mistake. JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

For some reason, my JS doesn't seem to be working on my page. I have done the node.js server before starting work on some of the more simple problems. I'm sure it's staring me right in my face but I cant spot it. I am trying to add rows to my table but it's not working. I have tried adding other js and nothing seems to be working, I know it's looking straight at me but I cant spot it. Many thanks.
Heres my index.html and index.js

```js
function addBat() {
  var table = document.getElementById("batters"),
    [0];
  var newBat = document.getElementById('batterName').value;

  var newRow = table.InsertRow(1);
  var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  cel1.innerHTML = newBat;
}


function init() {
  document.getElementById('addBatter').addEventListener('click', addBat);

}

window.addEventListener("load", init);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <script src=index.js></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title> Portsmouth Premier League</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="AUlogo"> <img src="Athletic-Union.jpg" alt="AU Logo">
  </div>
  <h1> Portsmouth Premier League </h1>
  <div id="clockbox" align='center'></div>

  <a href="addTeam.html"> Add Team </a>

  <div class="teams">
    <h2 id="team1"> Team 1 </h2>
    <h2 id="team2"> Team 2 </h2>
  </div>

  <div class="scores">
    <h2 id="team1Score"> Score 1 </h2>
    <h2 id="team2Score"> Score 2 </h2>
    <hr />
  </div>

  <div class="balls">
    <button type="button">0</button>
    <button type="button">1</button>
    <button type="button">2</button>
    <button type="button">3</button>
    <button type="button">4</button>
    <button type="button">5</button>
    <button type="button">6</button>
    <button type="button">w</button>
    <button type="button">nb</button>
    <button type="button">+</button>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="bowling">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Overs</th>
        <th>Runs</th>
        <th>Wickets</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bowler 1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>

    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="batting">
    Add Batter: <input type="text" name="batterName" id="batterName" />
    <button id="addBatter">Add</button>

    <table id="batters">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Runs</th>
        <th>Balls</th>
        <th>How Out</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Batter 1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Batter 2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `var table = document.getElementById("batters"),[0];` remove the comma

Comment: `var table = document.getElementById("batters"),
    [0];` Should be `var table = document.getElementById("batters")`

Answer (score 1):

Two problems I can see:

- you have a rogue `, [0]` in your `addBat` function
- you've capitalized the `insertRow` function

Also, your question isn't actually clear about what specifically isn't working. Are there other things that should be happening?

```js
function addBat() {
  var table = document.getElementById("batters");
  var newBat = document.getElementById('batterName').value;

  var newRow = table.insertRow(1);
  var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  cel1.innerHTML = newBat;
}


function init() {
  document.getElementById('addBatter').addEventListener('click', addBat);

}

window.addEventListener("load", init);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <script src=index.js></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title> Portsmouth Premier League</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="AUlogo"> <img src="Athletic-Union.jpg" alt="AU Logo">
  </div>
  <h1> Portsmouth Premier League </h1>
  <div id="clockbox" align='center'></div>

  <a href="addTeam.html"> Add Team </a>

  <div class="teams">
    <h2 id="team1"> Team 1 </h2>
    <h2 id="team2"> Team 2 </h2>
  </div>

  <div class="scores">
    <h2 id="team1Score"> Score 1 </h2>
    <h2 id="team2Score"> Score 2 </h2>
    <hr />
  </div>

  <div class="balls">
    <button type="button">0</button>
    <button type="button">1</button>
    <button type="button">2</button>
    <button type="button">3</button>
    <button type="button">4</button>
    <button type="button">5</button>
    <button type="button">6</button>
    <button type="button">w</button>
    <button type="button">nb</button>
    <button type="button">+</button>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="bowling">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Overs</th>
        <th>Runs</th>
        <th>Wickets</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bowler 1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>

    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="batting">
    Add Batter: <input type="text" name="batterName" id="batterName" />
    <button id="addBatter">Add</button>

    <table id="batters">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Runs</th>
        <th>Balls</th>
        <th>How Out</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Batter 1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Batter 2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```